# Patterns for filling in-memory databases with testing data

Tags: java, database, hsqldb

I would like to know what would be the best way to fill in memory database for testing with test data - how to manage such data, how to make simple insert scripts, what are good tools to support this ect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is the one taken by [DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/), which offers classes to export and import table content to and from XML files. You can use it to (re-)load your tables with a predetermined set of test data.

Answer (score 1):

I see two approaches:

1. Generate data, with [this for example](http://www.andygibson.net/blog/article/generate-test-data-with-datafactory/)
2. Use a subset of real data, that can be extracted with [this, keeping referential integrity etc](http://jailer.sourceforge.net/)